# receiving email POP3 and save in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I would like to continuously retrieve my emails via POP3 in my RoR-Projekt

where and what should I have to set so that the mails are received.

After that I have a table called "messages" with 
string: "email", string: "subject" and text: "text"

I would like to check if messages.email is the same like sender.of.email
and
messages.subject is the same like sender.of.email.subject
if it is true save email text to  messages.text

else
delete email

do that work with ActionMailer do i need a gem? how do that all work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of Rails, you might have mikel's excellent [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). If not you should use it anyway.

Use it to retrieve the messages from you POP3 server, parse the email content and access the properties which you want to work with.

Comment: where i have to implement Mail.defaults ?? and do it check continuously for new mails?

Comment: you'll probably need a cron job or a daemon to check for new mail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great project called [dbMail](http://dbmail.org/) for storing emails in a database. Let dbMail handle the emails then process whatever you want with any language that can access the database.

Comment: I am looking for a gem or implement with ActionMailer do not want to use other software

Answer (score 0):

i did it wiht Mailman gem.

more infos you can find:

http://dansowter.com/mailman-guide/

i have some other problems with the output/display  of a mail
but i hope i will fixed it with some help